# Best Practices for Using Brass Standoffs Electrically?

Tags: pcb

I'm working on a project where I am trying to eliminate some cable assembly and connector costs. In my particular project I happen to have three brass standoffs that join together two boards. Board one is the mainboard, containing the power, mcu, and so on. The board I am joining to is essentially a single channel touch sensor. Right now I use JST connectors to get the job done and they work great, but add connector and cable assembly costs. I am contemplating just using the brass standoffs as the electrical connectors (already need to be there) and adding copper pads to both the boards to get the job done.

I understand people do this sort of thing but in researching mechanical solutions it looks like I'd just end up adding cost in terms of washers, since they have to be brass too and are not exactly cheap (washer suggestions welcome, btw) and they bring their own problems.

Is it a terrible idea to try and solve this with some loctite or hot glue? The design won't be subjected to extreme vibration or anything like that.

In general, is using standoffs electrically to be avoided? I would appreciate any sage wisdom on this topic.

Comment: *" I am contemplating just using the brass standoffs  ...*" as electrical conductors between the two boards? You might clarify in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor -- added.

Comment: Maybe consider mezzanine connectors? Or pogo connectors + pads on the other PCB. Even the regular 0.1in headers would work, no?

Comment: The idea has attractions but may complicate debugging / fault-finding. I don't know the answer but you'd need to consider whether the PCB tracks are plated or not and whether the standoffs are nickel-plated or not. I'd be inclined to use star washers between the pillar and the board to bite through any  oxidation.

Comment: Run a piece of copper wire between the boards and solder. The wire can be as heavy as you need.

Comment: @Gil You just invented a worse form of the extra wire he wants to get rid of. One that adds an extra component and an extra step but can't even be disassembled.

Comment: things to look into: (1) if there is any condensation /moisture, effect of galvanic  series, esp. if more voltage/current compared to a chassis ground connection (2) unplated brass will slowly corrode anyway from what I understand. I vaguely recall having an electrical "touch-off" automated alignment part that had to have its material changed after surface conductivity issues developed.

Comment: One other cost factor, if you have standoffs at voltage, that's a pretty big piece of bare conductor, especially for long standoffs, so you might want an insulator tube around the non-ground ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite common to connect to chassis trough these connectors, so why not a signal? I kinda like the idea. Integrety-wise it would be a bit shady when considering return currents, current loops and that kind of thing, but as long as you factor that in it could work.

Star washers has been mentioned; I would never *ever* use star-washers anywhere near a PCB. If used on a PCB it will just dig *through* the copper, so that will not at all be helpfull. Any star-washer will create a fine metal dust during vibration. Needless to say that can be lethal for a circuit even if the star-washer is on a mechanical assembly nearby. What you want is a copper-beryllium crinkle washers, and probably an ENIG surface-finish on the PCB.

I am not sure if brass is the most ideal standoff material, but how worried you need to be on oxidation depends on the enviorment.